# How to get the last 10 item data in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Person model, and I want to query out the last 10 items.

I can easily query 10 items from front by slice:

```
Person.objects.all()[:10]
```

But I can not query 10 row data backwards.

I tried use `Person.objects.all()[-10:]`, but failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to order it descending then slice it

```
Person.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:10]
```

> Notice the `-` before `created`.

Comment: You should mention that this produces the items the OP wants, but in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Which column you ordered by?
order by `id`：

```
Person.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use negative indexes in QuerySet.

You can inverted order the id, then slice it:

```
Person.objects.order_by('-id')[:10]
```